# number of hard links to a empty pipe linux vs unix

Tags: c, linux, unix

This is what I found when I was working on one of my course projects. Below is the C code block to print out the information about an empty pipe which has not connected to any process yet.

```
{
 int pfd[2], nread;
 char s[100];
 struct stat pipe_info;
 if (pipe(pfd) == -1)
 {
     perror ("pipe");
     return (-1);
 }

 if (fstat (pfd[0], &pipe_info) < 0)
     perror ("fstat");

 print_info (&pipe_info);

 if (fstat (pfd[1], &pipe_info) < 0)
     perror ("fstat");

 print_info (&pipe_info);

 return(0);
}

void print_info (struct stat *pipe_info)
{
    printf ("mode %o\n", pipe_info->st_mode);
    printf ("inode %d\n", pipe_info->st_ino);
    printf ("device %d\n", pipe_info->st_dev);
    printf ("minor device %d\n", pipe_info->st_rdev);
    printf ("num links %d\n", pipe_info->st_nlink);
    printf ("uid %d\n", pipe_info->st_uid);
    printf ("gid %d\n", pipe_info->st_gid);
    printf ("size %d\n", pipe_info->st_size);
    printf ("atime %d\n", pipe_info->st_atime);
    printf ("mtime %d\n", pipe_info->st_mtime);
    printf ("ctime %d\n", pipe_info->st_ctime);
    printf ("block size %d\n", pipe_info->st_blksize);
    printf ("block %d\n", pipe_info->st_blocks);
}
```

I compiled the source code on both a Linux machine and a Solaris OS machine. What I found was that on the Linux machine, the number of links is 1 while on the Solaris OS machine, the number of links for the pipe is 0. I am fairly new to the kernels of both systems and would like to know why the number of links are different on the two systems?

Answer (score 3):

The [SunOS 5.10 / Solaris 2.x manual](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?fstat%202) says this about the `st_nlink` field:

> **st_nlink**      This field should be used only by  administrative commands.

which I read as "this field has a nonsensical value".

Contrariwise, the value for Linux makes sense: the pipe has a link to the process that created it. I expect that `st_nlink` would equal 2 once the other side was conected to a (forked) process. The Linux fstat claims POSIX compliance which is good. The Solaris man page I have makes no such claims.

If your underlying question is how can I tell if the farside of a pipe is connected, there are two answers:

1. Your program should know if it attached the farside
2. You can try to write the pipe and get some combination of EAGAIN, EWOULDBLOCK, EPIPE, or the SIGPIPE signal.

Option 2 would be problematic if the other side of the pipe is connected. You could work around it if you can create a message that would never be sent by the writer to be rejected by the reader.

Comment: Thanks, your post is helpful but I am not sure about the correctness of your statement-"this field has a nonsensical value".

Comment: Okay, replace my interpretation with "unless you have access to the source code, the semantics of nlink will not make sense to you.". I don't have source, and presumably neither do you because Solaris is proprietary software. By your own empirical test, Solaris yields an out-of-spec result, and neither of us can guess why. If I had a Solaris machine available to me there are a number of simple tests that could plumb the meaning of nlink under Solaris. This is what it was like in the bad old days when there were 30 different kernels all slightly different for no good reason except history.